# Make the outerline of a circle sized button bigger

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have the following css-file which is used for a javafx Button:

```
#circle {
-fx-background-color:
        green,
        white;
-fx-background-radius: 100;
-fx-background-insets: 0;
-fx-text-fill: black;
-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}
```

So its basically a circle shaped white button with a green outer line. My problem is that the green outer line is very thin. Is there any way to make the outer line bigger?

Answer (score 1):

Most of time, when you want a specific outer line, the border property is used.

```
#circle {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-color: green;
    -fx-border-radius: 100;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 100;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}
```

In order to get the same shape of your background, you have also have to set the `-fx-border-radius` to the same value than `-fx-background-radius`.

As its name indicates it, you can enlarge the border with the `-fx-border-width` property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the green outer line using `-fx-stroke` instead?
So like so:

```
#circle {
  -fx-background-color: white;
  -fx-stroke: green;
  -fx-stroke-width: 5;
  ...rest of the CSS
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but doesnt work sadly, the outer line just completly disappears that way.